# Eclipse specific colour change with new Ubuntu themes

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, themes

All but one colour is a problem in Eclipse with the new Ubuntu (10.10) dark themes.
I want to change only this one, not the theme.

This is the background/colour used by Eclipse in lists (Explorer, Open Resource) when an item is *pre* selected (a selected item displays ok).

The current display is white on light-grey, not easily readable.

Where can I change that?

Comment: A fully dark theme for Eclipse does exist now: see my edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update July 2012 (18 months later):

With the latest Eclipse4.2 (June 2012, "Juno") release, you won't depend on the OS colors anymore.
See the article by [Lars Vogel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548637/vogella) in "[Eclipse 4 is beautiful – Create your own Eclipse 4 theme](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2012/07/11/eclipse-4-is-beautiful-create-your-own-eclipse-4-theme/)":

[image: Eclipse fully dark theme]

> If you want to play with it, you only need to write a plug-in, create a CSS file and use the **`org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme`** extension point to point to your file.
>   If you export your plug-in, place it in the “dropins” folder of your Eclipse installation and your styling is available.

---

Original answer: December 2010

It is a system color (a background color based on the underlying OS system color properties), so you will have to change a property in the theme, not a setting in Eclipse.

For instance, see "[How to change the color of menu text?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7561/how-to-change-the-color-of-menu-text)" (but this may not be exactly how your dark theme works and you [will need to tweak the `~/.gnome*` files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5739/how-to-reset-gnome-default-theme))

Comment: Thanks. The new Ubuntu offers an easy way to change appearance colors, in System Preferences Apperance Customize, and I could fix a few problems with Eclipse (E.g. tooltip). Only this one is remaining  -  I was hoping there is a in-menu solution?

Comment: @ring0: if that one color (which I suspect is a system one) cannot be easily fixed with the "Customize" tool, then... it is a good question for http://askubuntu.com ;)

Answer (score 3):

just want to say that I had the same problem and that changing the "selected entry" text colour of the theme to #8C8C8C fixed it for me without hurting the themes "look and feel"